# How to add results of two select commands in same query

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I currently have two select commands as per below. What I would like to do is to add the results together in the SQL query rather than the variables in code.

```
select sum(hours) from resource;
select sum(hours) from projects-time;
```

Is it possible to have both in the same SQL and output a sum of both results?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yes. It is possible `:D`

```
SELECT  SUM(totalHours) totalHours
FROM
        ( 
            select sum(hours) totalHours from resource
            UNION ALL
            select sum(hours) totalHours from projects-time
        ) s
```

As a sidenote, the tablename `projects-time` must be delimited to avoid syntax error. Delimiter symbols vary on RDBMS you are using.

Comment: What is the s on the end? Is that a typo?

Comment: @Rhys no, it's an `ALIAS` of the subquery. by the way, What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: Its for a SQLITE DB through JDBC conenction from a web app

Comment: you also need to add double quotes around your table `projects-time`. like this, `select sum(hours) totalHours from "projects-time"`

Comment: I was using this very often ... UNION [ALL] ... it just did not come into my brain again ... I am getting old

Answer (score 35):

Something simple like this can be done using subqueries in the `select` clause:

```
select ((select sum(hours) from resource) +
        (select sum(hours) from projects-time)
       ) as totalHours
```

For such a simple query as this, such a subselect is reasonable.

In some databases, you might have to add `from dual` for the query to compile.

If you want to output each individually:

```
select (select sum(hours) from resource) as ResourceHours,
       (select sum(hours) from projects-time) as ProjectHours
```

If you want both *and* the sum, a subquery is handy:

```
select ResourceHours, ProjectHours, (ResourceHours+ProjecctHours) as TotalHours
from (select (select sum(hours) from resource) as ResourceHours,
             (select sum(hours) from projects-time) as ProjectHours
     ) t
```

Comment: I like this solution because it works for addition and subtraction

Comment: This solution (first example) doesn't work if one of the sums is NULL.

Answer (score 10):

`UNION ALL` once, aggregate once:

```
SELECT sum(hours) AS total_hours
FROM   (
   SELECT hours FROM resource
   UNION ALL
   SELECT hours FROM "projects-time" -- illegal name without quotes in most RDBMS
   ) x
```

Comment: @JW.: Being cautious since I don't know *all* .. :)

Comment: What is the `x` at the end for?

Answer (score 0):

Repeat for Multiple aggregations like:

```sql
SELECT sum(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT FROM ( 
    SELECT AMOUNT FROM table_1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT AMOUNT FROM table_2 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ASSURED_SUM FROM table_3
)
```

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to make multiple operation use

```
select (sel1.s1+sel2+s2)

(select sum(hours) s1 from resource) sel1
join 
(select sum(hours) s2 from projects-time)sel2
on sel1.s1=sel2.s2
```