# sum two select statements in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to produce the sum of these two select statements:

```
select sum(amount) as hr from friday.dbo.FMDR_Friday_CSV where [Account #] like 4010

select sum(amount) as hr from friday.dbo.FMDR_Friday_CSV where [Account #] like 4060
```

I've tried putting a union between them, which only serves to produce the two results in the same results window.

Thanks for any help, I'm an absolute beginner.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Thanks Mat, I've added the tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add results of two select commands in same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149775/how-to-add-results-of-two-select-commands-in-same-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the records come from the same table, a `UNION` is superfluous.A simple `IN` or `OR` is sufficient:

```
select sum(amount) as hr from friday.dbo.FMDR_Friday_CSV
where [Account #] in (4060, 4061)
```

---

```
select sum(amount) as hr from friday.dbo.FMDR_Friday_CSV
where [Account #] = 4060 OR [Account #] = 4061)
```

Answer (score 8):

In case you want to use multiple selects (maybe if other tables are involved)

```
select ((select sum(hours) from foo1) +
        (select sum(hours) from foo2)) as totalHours
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple OR will do:

```
 select sum(amount) as hr from friday.dbo.FMDR_Friday_CSV 
   where [Account #] like 4010 OR [Account #] like 4060
```

Answer (score 1):

whats wrong with :

```
select sum(amount) as hr from friday.dbo.FMDR_Friday_CSV
where [Account #] like 4010 or [Account #] like 4060
```

your second option is to use the `with`statement. read about it :)

Comment: `like` should not be used here. This is an explicit condition. Go with `=`.

Comment: True. But as an "absolute beginner", Adam may be expecting that `LIKE 4010` will return `14010`,`4010` or `40109`. The question didn't make clear if anything extra was required. Regardless, `LIKE` is not as clear as `=` in this case, and I've always been of the opinion that correct syntax should always be reinforced in answers, especially when working with new developers.