# Sum of two queries

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this:

[image]

I made two queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(column_1) AS result_1 FROM table WHERE column_1= 5;
SELECT COUNT(column_2) AS result_2 FROM table WHERE column_2 = 5;
```

The first query gives me result_1 = 2, and the second result_2 = 3

I need to make a query that will give me the sum of these two (2+3=5).
I always get two results or just one of them.

Comment: What does "the sum of these two" mean? This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. You don't. You don't even give an example so we can't even guess what that is. [mcve]

Comment: I fixed my question. I hope it's clearer now. I apologize for the misunderstanding. Thanks

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. (A [mcve] is cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation.) PS You still don't say what table you want back. Also, find out what a scalar subquery is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add results of two select commands in same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149775/how-to-add-results-of-two-select-commands-in-same-query)

Comment: (Obviously--) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS It's still not clear how much details the particular example queries you give and/or their similar structure is part of the question you want to ask. Eg Maybe you just care about (select ...) + (select ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subqueries:

```sql
SELECT sub1.result_1 + sub2.result_2 FROM (
SELECT COUNT(column_1) AS result_1 FROM table WHERE column_1 = 5) as sub1, (
SELECT COUNT(column_2) AS result_2 FROM table WHERE column_2 = 5) as sub2
```

Comment: That's it. Thank You!

Comment: @Midhat & PatrickPorto The cross join (comma) is a pointless complication, just select the sum of the scalar subqueries. See answers to the many duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Each of these expressions:

```
column_1 = 5
```

and

```
column_2 = 5
```

evaluates to 0 or 1 (false or true). 
So you can use them like this:

```
SELECT SUM(column_1 = 5) + SUM(column_2 = 5) AS result FROM table
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fqZfx8A3AuZwYsDyuA8fF9/0).
Result:

```
| result |
| ------ |
| 5      |
```

Comment: I need sum of two count